# How to get data from excel cell but not the format in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I am new to Python. I want to ask that how to get cell data from excel but not the format?
[PICTURE1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TagDY.png) this is what I have in the column L34 but [PICTURE2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0cGv.png) this is the format of the cell. So if now I print the value in
`wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx') ws = wb.active print(ws['L34'])`
Python it will show the this <Cell 'Sheet1'.L34> but what I want is the 1280.00 for my result. Anyone can help for this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Load the excel sheet using the `data_only` attribute

```
wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

On other option is to calculate each row and get the result. See the sample as following. This will work if your file is a .csv.

The sample excel:

[image]

The code to get sum of the each row. You may edit according to your requirement.

```
import csv
import sys, datetime, time
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
import time

i = 1

with open("test_numbers.csv") as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)

    for row in csvreader:
        row_l = row[0].split(";")
        #print(row_l)
        if (row_l[0] or row_l[1]).isdigit():
            print(f"The result for row{i} = {int(row_l[0])+int(row_l[1])}")
            i = i + 1
        else:
            i = i + 1
```

The code's output:

[image]